# How to debug my activity for TFS?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

I want to automate building patches with WIX. Cause it seems to be no tools for it I write my own. But I don't know how to debug it. I can find only rubbish tutorials like [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/baruchf/archive/2009/07/02/debugging-team-build-now-you-can.aspx) that are useless 'cause it doesn't work. Build just fails but don't stop on a breakpoint (at least if the breakpoint is in the agent scope). Don't mention that the debugger doesn't enter into my activity.

Tell me please what is the way to debug my own activity in fact, some way that really works.

Answer (score 0):

1. To debug on your server your have to copy and run the remotedebugger on the server and connect from your local visual studio. A copy of it is located under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86. [Ewald Hofman shows how this can be done](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-12-How-to-debug-my-custom-activities.aspx)
2. You can also run and debug your activity on your local computer within a UnitTest or some other program using the following code:

   ```
   MyActivity activity = new MyActivity ();
   var Arguments = new Dictionary
       {
          {"MyInArgument","somestringvalue"},
          {"MyInArgument2",true}  
       };

   var output = System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity, Arguments);
   ```

I use the second way quite often and the first only when there are troubles with the server.

Comment: May be I'll try the second way if there's no better solution. But I don't need a remote debugger for it 'cause I'm creating just some tool for internal usage and I debug it on only one VirtualBox machine with both VS and TFS (so they are on the same machine), not on a server for real usage. Unfortunantelly, it doesn't simplify debugging much.

Comment: It should be possible to debug also programs running in the vm with remote debugger. Server or VM should not make a difference.